# Calling sub GUI from main GUI in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matlab-guide

I have a user interactive main GUI supposedly named `main_gui` which I call with some input variables and after user selection I get some output.

In this main GUI I call a sub GUI called `sub_gui` in which I do almost the same thing as the main GUI. The output from `sub_gui` is used to recalculate values in `main_gui` and make the appropriate plots.

Now the problem I am facing is I am using `uiwait` in the opening function of `main_gui` so that it does not close before the user closes the GUI itself. This gives problem in debugging so its workaround will also be helpful.

I want to call the `sub_gui` by pressing a command button `cmd_second_gui`.

I read I can do this by using `uiwait` but I am not able to deduce how to do it.
Some help will be deeply appreciated.

When I call `sub_gui` I dont want my `main_gui` to close but to be in the background and when I close the `sub_gui` the `main_gui` resuface and appropriate plot be made based upon the parameter I get from `sub_gui`. I hope what I want to do is clear, if any more description is needed kindly ask.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever I have a main GUI whose buttons can call more GUIs, this is what I do:

1. In the m-files of all the GUIs except the main GUI, I set the 'visibility' attribute to 'off'.. The 'visibility' of the main GUI should be 'on'.
2. Run all the m-files (All the GUIs are run, however, only the main GUI is visible)
3. Based on button clicks in the main GUI, I turn the visibility 'on' for the desired GUI panel.
4. The closefunctions of the GUI m-files can be used to control the order of closing the GUIs

Note: I have not used uiwait for any of these requirements.

Let me know you need more info.